# How to join MongoDB collections in query builder using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, query-builder

How do i perform MongoDB join equivalent in query builder using PHP. 
Is there a way to connect collections.
I think if we put the value for "_id" in collection col1 to the other "model_id" in collection col2.

"col1 collection is normal document and col2 collection is embedded document".

Example collection:-

**col1:**

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "model_status" : "A",
}
```

**col2:**

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "infodetails" : [ 
        {
            "info_name" : "test",
        }
    ],    
    "test_model" : [ 
        {
            "model_id" : "2",
            "model_name" : "B",
        }, 
        {
            "model_id" : "3",
            "model_name" : "C",
        }, 
        {
            "model_id" : "1",
            "model_name" : "A",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Anyone know the solution for above query.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my above query, This will works perfectly.

```
======
Query:-
======
require_once(MONGODBPATH);
$mdb = mongoConnection::getMongoConnection();
$col2 = $mdb->selectDB("DB")->selectCollection("col2");
$ops =  array(
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                                "_id" => 1,
                                "test_model"   => 1,
                            )
            ),
            array('$unwind' => '$test_model'),
            array(
                '$lookup' => array(
                                'from'=>'col1',
                                'localField'=> "test_model.model_id",
                                'foreignField' => "_id",
                                'as'=> "result_foreignField"
                            )
            ),
        );
$results = $col2->aggregate($ops);

=========
Output:-
=========
Array
(
    [waitedMS] => 0
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => 1
                    [test_model] => Array
                        (
                            [model_id] => 1
                            [model_name] => A
                        )

                    [result_foreignField] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [_id] => 1
                                    [model_status] => A
                                )

                        )

                )
        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```